# How to access rooms and resources in Domino server using java?

Tags: java, lotus-domino

this is used for establishing session with domino server
Now I have to access its all room and resources 
How to do it?

```
try 
{
s = NotesFactory.createSession("110.45.105.00", "simple111@mobi.com", "test@232123");
// Database db = session.getDatabase(null, "ConnectmetoDomino.nsf");
db=s.getDatabase("","Room12.nsf");
System.out.println(s.getUserName());
            //db = s.getDatabase("10.55.165.20", s.getAddressBooks().elementAt(0).toString());
String user = s.getUserName();
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you need to do - there's already a line opening a Room12.nsf database .. is that the one you want to get to ?